# Datepicker Angular bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker, and I want to use the following input format 'ddMMyyyy' on my input. Actually the ng-change is called when type this format in the input, but I want the input changes to the format to 'dd/MM/yyyy' after ng-change, just like when you select a date inside the datepicker calendar. How can I do that?
Here a plnkr example code

https://plnkr.co/edit/Njetw7fVfZATxruuUI3m?p=preview

```
 angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  $scope.inlineOptions = {
    customClass: getDayClass,
    minDate: new Date(),
    showWeeks: true
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    dateDisabled: disabled,
    formatYear: 'yy',
    maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
    minDate: new Date(),
    startingDay: 1
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  function disabled(data) {
    var date = data.date,
      mode = data.mode;
    return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
  }

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.inlineOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate ? null : new Date();
    $scope.dateOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate;
  };

  $scope.toggleMin();

  $scope.open1 = function() {
    $scope.popup1.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.open2 = function() {
    $scope.popup2.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
    $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
  };

  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
  $scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy', 'ddMMyyyy'];

  $scope.popup1 = {
    opened: false
  };

  $scope.popup2 = {
    opened: false
  };

  var tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  var afterTomorrow = new Date();
  afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  $scope.events = [
    {
      date: tomorrow,
      status: 'full'
    },
    {
      date: afterTomorrow,
      status: 'partially'
    }
  ];

  function getDayClass(data) {
    var date = data.date,
      mode = data.mode;
    if (mode === 'day') {
      var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
        var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

        if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
          return $scope.events[i].status;
        }
      }
    }

    return '';
  }
});
```

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: why would you not use the format you want to start with? Seems like you are asking for problems if user decides to change that date

Comment: when you select the date it should be in 'ddMMyyyy'  you dont want ngchange event!! am i correct?

Comment: I want to type the date in this format 'ddMMyyyy', and after that, I want the date transforms into dd/MM/yyyy. I just don't want to show the empty mask. Maybe I'm complicating too much this task, but is there a good way to do that?